# Windows Mobile: how to highlight row in datagrid and compilation delays

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, datagrid

I have two Windows mobile questions:

1. how to Highlight row in datagrid (after i run any query) ?
2. why after 20-30 compilation, it takes for 6-7 minutes to compile (the first time takes 1 minute)?

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: You really should not ask two unrelated questions in one. If you had asked it as two separate questions, you'd also been able to use a meaningful title.

Answer (score 1):

For #1, take a look at Ilya Tumanov's example of [custom formatting data in the DataGrid](http://blogs.msdn.com/netcfteam/archive/2006/04/25/583542.aspx). He does custom painting of cells in it.  THis is how you'd "highlight" a row.

For #2, there's something wrong with your environment.  I've not seen this or heard it reported and I've been using Studio for developing CF apps for a while now, with well over 10-30 compiles in a run.  My guess is you have a network drive mapped.  Unmap it and see if anything changes (though 6-7 minutes is really heinous).  Also, if you're using a solution with a lot of projects, you should have a single output directory for everything instead of each project having their own, and set CopyLocal to false on all the references.  This helps keep disk access duriong build to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

For #2: If you're using Visual Studio 2008 it may as well be a matter of PostBuild verification task. The following link pointed me in the right direction when I had the problem:

http://blogs.msdn.com/vsdteam/archive/2006/09/15/756400.aspx